# Error while running Guard on Windows (SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, guard

I am trying to learn Ruby by following the railstutorial.org website. I am at the automated tests part, running Guard but it throws an error:

```
C:\Users\Thomas\Documents\Development\teachmtg.com [master]> bundle exec guard
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.8.1/lib/guard/dsl.rb:119:in `instance_eval': C:/Users/Thomas/Documents/Development/teachmtg.com/Guardfile:4: syntax error, unexpected ',' (SyntaxError)
guard 'rspec', :version => 2 do, :all_after_pass => false do
                                ^
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.8.1/lib/guard/dsl.rb:119:in `instance_eval_guardfile'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.8.1/lib/guard/dsl.rb:74:in `evaluate_guardfile'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.8.1/lib/guard.rb:147:in `setup_from_guardfile'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.8.1/lib/guard.rb:63:in `setup'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.8.1/lib/guard.rb:188:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.8.1/lib/guard/cli.rb:110:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.8.1/bin/guard:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/guard:23:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/guard:23:in `<main>'
```

As I am completely new to Ruby and Rails, I have no idea where to look, what to look for, etc.

Can you give me a few tips and pointers ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `do` from `:version => 2 do, :all_after_pass ...` expression in Guardfile.